# Remove page from "back stack"

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

I am using cordova for an application, one part of the application is that I need to go to another screen, then return back to the previous with some data, I do that by passing some data in a get request and that is all fine, I have data persistence working as it should, now the only problem I face is when someone presses back and they are returned to the separate page instead of the page "they were on before".

Is there any way to tell that the user pressed back to get to that page. With that said, is there any way to force the user to go back again if the user pressed back.

For example....

main screen > secondary > picks date from another screen > returns to secondary > presses back > this should be the main screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did this was to implement my own back stack using javascript, `History.js` and `window.localStorage`.

Comment: Golly. Use angular js yoo

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the javascript events to customize ur handling of  back button , something along those lines  -

```
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function (e) {
          alert("back button pressed");          
           return(false) //not required if default behaviour is also intended  
       });
```

Comment: Hmm, I will test it when I get to work. :). Will tell you soon.